# PHP Insert Into MultiDimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a functon that is passed an array of url's. I am extracting data from each webpage and then assigning each piece of data to an array. Here's my function:

```
 function getitems ($urls) {
  $iteminfo = array();
  foreach($urls as $link) {
   $circdl = my_curl($link);
   $circqp = htmlqp($circdl,'body');
   $itemtitle = $circqp->branch()->find('div[class="col-item"]')->children('img')->attr('title');
   $itemlink = $circqp->branch()->find('div[class="col-item"]')->children('img')->attr('src');
   $itemdesc = $circqp->branch()->find('div[class="col-item"]')->children('img')->attr('alt');
   $iteminfo[][] = $itemtitle;
   //$iteminfo[$itemtitle][] = $itemlink;
   //$iteminfo[$itemtitle][] = $itemdesc;
  }
    return $iteminfo;  
 }
```

I want the array to look like this:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => title [1] => link [2] => desc ) [1] => Array ( [0] => title [1] => link [2] => desc ) [2] => Array ( [0] => title [1] => link [2] => desc ) )
```

But I can't wrap my head around how to additional fields to the sub-arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
function getitems ($urls) {
    $iteminfo = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($urls as $link) {
        $circdl = my_curl($link);
        $circqp = htmlqp($circdl,'body');
        $itemtitle = $circqp->branch()->find('div[class="col-item"]')->children('img')->attr('title');
        $itemlink = $circqp->branch()->find('div[class="col-item"]')->children('img')->attr('src');
        $itemdesc = $circqp->branch()->find('div[class="col-item"]')->children('img')->attr('alt');
        $iteminfo[$i][] = $itemtitle;
        $iteminfo[$i][] = $itemlink;
        $iteminfo[$i][] = $itemdesc;
        $i++;
    }
    return $iteminfo;  
}
```

Everything is ok, you just have to assign index to each of your rows.

Comment: There are better ways to do this task than maintaining a counter variable.  See other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly...

```
$iteminfo[] = array($itemtitle, $itemlink, $itemdesc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily replace

```
$iteminfo[][] = $itemtitle;
//$iteminfo[$itemtitle][] = $itemlink;
//$iteminfo[$itemtitle][] = $itemdesc;
```

with

```
$iteminfo = array($itemtitle, $itemlink, $itemdesc);
```

You can do this because the syntax

```
$array = $element; // where     $array = array();
```

is just another way to add element to an array in PHP and `$element` can be an `array()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getitems ($urls) {
   $iteminfo = array();
   foreach($urls as $link) {
       $subInfo = array();
       $circdl = my_curl($link);
       $circqp = htmlqp($circdl,'body');
       $subInfo[] = $circqp->branch()->find('div[class="col-item"]')->children('img')->attr('title');
       $subInfo[] = $circqp->branch()->find('div[class="col-item"]')->children('img')->attr('src');
       $subInfo[] = $circqp->branch()->find('div[class="col-item"]')->children('img')->attr('alt');
      $iteminfo[] = $subInfo;
   }
   return $iteminfo;  
}
```